# A javascript statement that I haven't seen before

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am inspecting some Javascript code written in UnderscoreJS. In this, there are quite a few instances of JS code being written like this:

```
if(length === +length){ //do something}
```

or

```
if(length !== +length){ //do something }
```

What exactly does this compute to? I have never seen this before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (length === +length)
```

It makes sure that the `length` is actually a numeric value.

Two things to understand here,

1. [The Strict equality operator, will evaluate to `true` only when the objects are the same](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6). In JavaScript, the numbers and strings are immutables. So, when you compare two numbers, the Number values will be compared.
2. Unary `+` operator will try to get the numeric value of any object. If the object is already of type `Number`, it will not make any changes and return the object as it is.

In this case, if `length` is actually a number in string format, lets say `"1"`, the expression

```
"1" == +"1"
```

will evaluate to be `true`, because `"1"` is coerced to numeric `1` internally and compared. But

```
"1" === +"1"
```

which will be transformed to

```
"1" === 1
```

and that will not undergo coercion and since the types are different, `===` will evaluate to `false`. And if `length` is of any other type, `===` will straight away return `false`, as the right hand side is a number.

You can think of this check as a shorthand version of this

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(length) === "[object Number]")
```

Comment: _"will evaluate to Truthy/Falsy"_ - I'm not sure about this. It simply evaluates to `Boolean` `true` or `false`.

Comment: Is there any advantage to the alternative approach you've suggested over `typeof length === "number"`?

Comment: @TomFenech In this particular case, they both are okay, but `typeof` will return `object` with `null`.

Answer (score 3):

It is a way of testing whether a value is numeric. See this for example:

```
> length="string"
> length === +length
false
> length=2
> length === +length
true
```

The unary `+` converts the variable `length` to the Number type, so if it was already numeric then the identity will be satisfied.

The use of the identity operator `===` rather than the equality operator `==` is important here, as it does a strict comparison of both the value and the type of the operands.

Perhaps a more explicit (but slightly longer to write) way of performing the same test would be to use:

```
typeof length === "number"
```